# is this the right method instead using bottom bar navigation

Tags: flutter

I am new to Flutter. As I understand Bottom Bar Navigation is used for quick navigation between the top-level views of an app. but in my situation, I want to use like this which only button PAY can be clicked.
[image]

so is it okay if Im not using BottomBar instead i use as container and place it at bottom?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ya ,The best way is that you can create a container and the button and place it child of bottomNavigationBar so the flutter is automaticaly align it in bottom side

`bottomNavigationBar: Container(child: yourcodeHere),`

Comment: try yours method, but is doesnt assigned to my bottom side

Comment: but when I want to call the class, it keep automatically  BottomNavigationBar(items: items), <---- what is it means?